# How do I upload a file to Azure blob storage from a MVC view

Tags: azure, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC5 internet application and would like some help to upload a file from my own filesystem to an Azure Blob.

Here is my Azure upload code function:

```
public void UploadFileToBlobStorage(string containerName, string blockBlogName, string fileName)
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

    // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    container.SetPermissions(
        new BlobContainerPermissions
        {
            PublicAccess =
                BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        }); 

    // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blockBlogName);

    // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Here is my function to upload a test file:

```
public void UploadTestFile(string localFileName)
{
    string containerName = "TestContainer";
    string blockBlogName = "Test.txt";
    AzureService azureService = new AzureService();
    azureService.UploadFileToBlobStorage(containerName, blockBlogName, localFileName);
}
```

I am not sure how to call the UploadTestFile() function from a MVC View where the user can browse to a file to upload.

Do I need to use Ajax, or can I simply upload a file by calling the method from a MVC view? Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to call your UploadTestFile() function from an MVC View is by using the Html.BeginForm() method. I am including an example below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadTestFile", "INSERT_YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME_HERE", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    <span>
        <input type="file" name="myFile" multiple /> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </span>

}
```

Also, a couple of suggestions on your code:

1. UploadFileToBlobStorage(): The code checks for container existence and setting permissions on every request. I would recommend separating the container.CreateIfNotExists() and container.SetPermissions(…) logic into a separate initialization function that needs to be executed only once on first deployment.
2. UploadFileToBlobStorage(): It looks like the code will try to upload the localFileName from the VM file system and not the multi-part form data. One approach would be to use the HttpFileCollectionBase class and the Controller.Request property. Example below:

   ```
   public void UploadFileToBlobStorage(
       string containerName, 
       string blockBlogName, 
       HttpFileCollectionBase files) 
   {

       // .....

       // Use this:
       blockBlob.UploadFromStream(files[0].InputStream); 

       /* uploading the first file: 
          you can enumerate thru the files collection 
          if you are uploading multiple files */

       /* Instead of this: 
          Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents 
          from a local file. */
       using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)) 
       {
           blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
       }
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public void UploadTestFile() 
   {
       string containerName = "TestContainer";
       string blockBlogName = "Test.txt";
       AzureService azureService = new AzureService();

       // Notice the Request.Files instead of localFileName
       azureService.UploadFileToBlobStorage(
             containerName, blockBlogName, Request.Files);
   }
   ```

Please let me know if that works on your end.